# Allow visitors to add or remove web parts in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, personalization

Outside of the "My Site" page in SharePoint, is there any way to allow my sites visitors/users to add or remove web parts on pages without giving them contributor writes? I'm working on a corporate intranet that is being built with SharePoint and they want the home page of the site to be highly personalizable. But besides the "My Site" page, I don't know of any way to allow all of the visitors to add or remove web parts. Can anyone provide any guidance? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with a publishing site on sp2010, and the permissions you need are:

### Site Permissions

- Add and Customize Pages
- Browse Directories

### Personal Permissions

- Add/Remove Personal Web Parts
- Update Personal Web Parts

The personal web part permissions dont work on their own

Comment: Do I have to add a role using the object model and then associate this role with a group (or user). I did this on SP 2007 and so far I don't see any option to "edit" page to add or remove any web parts. Do I need to do something special to my web parts?

Comment: there should be a "Personalise this Page" link under the welcome control, just under "Sign Out"

Comment: Ahh, I was looking for it on the Site Actions menu. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own permission set, where you should set "Add/Remove Private Web Parts" permission and "Update Personal Web Parts" permission, but remove those permissions which you don't like in "Contributor" permission set. Then assign this new permission set to users or groups you need.